# Add parameter when you inherit abstract class?

Tags: c#, variables, inheritance, abstract, radix

Book class inherits abstract class Goods. Book method has same parameters as Goods method. But also has numPages, why is that?

public Book(string title, string barCode, double price, int numPages)

If I had a class inherit Book class, do I have to put all the same parameters and make a new one as well?

public Author(string title, string barCode, double price, int numPages, string author)

I hope this makes any sense.

```
  abstract class Goods
    {
        public decimal weight; 
        string Title, BarCode;
        double Price;
        public Goods(string title, string barCode, double price)
        {
            Title = title;
            BarCode = barCode;
            Price = price;
        }
    }

    abstract class Book : Goods
    {
        protected int NumPages;
        public Book(string title, string barCode, double price, int numPages)
            : base(title, barCode, price)
        {
            NumPages = numPages;
            weight = 1;
        }
```

Comment: `Do you have to add a variable to a method that has :base?` No. You can test this yourself by removing `NumPages` and verifying that it still works.

Comment: A *"method that has `:base`"* is a constructor. And no, you don't *have* to add any variable to it. But it's not clear to me if you're asking if you have to replicate the original constructor if you want to add a variable to the constructor list for the child class. What do you mean by "add a variable to it"? In other words, it's perfectly fine to add a new property (or protected field in your case) without adding an initializer for it in the constructor.

Comment: The question isn't quite clear. But when it comes to abstract classes, the compiler will give you an error if you try to do something you can't or don't do something that you must. So if the question is what you have to do, that's an easy way to tell. Or are you asking what you should do?

Answer (score 0):

> If I had a class inherit Book class, do I have to put all the same parameters and make a new one as well?

No, you don't have to, if Book class can provide some values for Goods class constructor at the beginning of the constructor.

```
public Book(string title, double price, int numPages)
    : base(title, price, 100) {
```

Unless, no way other than putting the same parameters in the subclass's constructor.

It is because

> Instance constructors, which you call to create a new instance of the class. Each class must define its own constructors.

which is explained in [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance), and subclass must call one of constructors provided by the base class explicitly or implicitly.

`: base(title, barCode, price)` in your code is the explicit way. Even if Book class didn't have constructor or had a constructor with no parameter, you could do the implicit way, where you can omit the code `: base()`.

Another thing you could consider is to get rid of constructor parameters which is for optional field. Such fields can be populated as properties. `BarCode` in the code below is the example. Then, the subclass does not need to have code for `BarCode`.

But reading [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer), be well aware of the order of initilizations with object initializer. In some case, it cannot be equivalent, although it does not matter in the provided simple code.

```
abstract class Goods {
    public decimal weight;
    string Title, GoodsType;
    public string BarCode { get; set; }
    double Price;
    public Goods(string title, double price) {
        Title = title;
        GoodsType = goodsType;
        Price = price;
    }
}

class Book : Goods {
    protected int NumPages;
    public Book(string title, double price, int numPages)
        : base(title, price) {
        NumPages = numPages;
        weight = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question included the phrase, ***"...do I have to...make a new one as well"***. The answer to that is "no". You *can* add a constructor with new parameters to initialize properties/fields, but it's not required. In the original example, this is perfectly legal syntax: `public Book() : base("", 0, "") { }`. The only requirement is that you call one of the base class constructors if any are explicitly defined.

Comment: And technically you don't *have* to define one at all (as long as the base class doesn't define one), since C# will generate a default constructor for you, which will initialize all fields to their default values ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors))

Comment: @RufusL Thanks for your point out. yes, that's right. I was implicitly assuming that she don't have default value for Goods constructor's parameters in Book class, so that I mentioned about `base(title, price, "book")` as an option. but, reading my answer again, I think you're right. such assumption makes confusion. I'll correct it. I don't have time at the moment, so I will edit my answer a little later.

Comment: @RufusL In terms of the default constructor, I intended that `or implicitly` in my answer represents it. I will try to mention it more clearly. but I was thinking the provided base abstract class that has a constructor with parameter is a part of this question. I wonder if it is a specific question for the provided code or general c# syntax question...

Comment: I think it was for the specific code, was just providing some additional details, since the second text in yellow says each client *must* define it's own constructors.

Comment: @KittyEstrella, A question about your question. The provided base abstract class that has a constructor with parameter is a part of this question? I'm wondering if it is a specific question for the provided code or general c# syntax question. my answer would be a bit differently written in either case.

Comment: Corrected my answer